# Error when using hyperref and thmtools

Tags: hyperref, amsthm, thmtools

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{plain}

    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

    \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
    \label{lemma:1.11}
    Lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}[Proof of \texorpdfstring{\hyperref[lemma:1.1]{Lemma 1.1}}{Lemma 1.1}]
    Proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

This throws

```
Package hyperref Info: bookmark level for unknown lemma defaults to 0 on input
line 19.
! Argument of \Hy@babelnormalise has an extra }.
```

How can I fix this?

I noticed that removing the thmtools package solves the problem, but I need it, so that's not a valid solution.

Comment: Why did you load hyperref twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `hyperref` should be loaded after most package, with exceptions like `cleveref`.

`thmtools` does protected `\edef` to the optional proof title, so the fragile command `\texorpdfstring` should be protected. `\hyperref` is robust.

```tex
\protect\texorpdfstring{\hyperref[lemma:1.1]{Lemma 1.1}}{Lemma 1.1}
```

Furthermore the burdensome `\texorpdfstring{\hyperref[<label>]{<text>}}{<text>}` can be simplified to `\autoref*{<label>}`. The starred form of `\autoref` will not add links, and `\autoref` is already handled by the bookmark mechanism of `hyperref`.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
    \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{lemma}
    \label{lemma:1.11}
    Lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}[Proof of \autoref*{lemma:1.11}]
    Proof.
\end{proof}

\section{Test use in bookmarks \autoref*{lemma:1.11}}

\end{document}
```

[image: output for \autoref* example]

Answer (score 1):

Though muzimuzhi Z already gave a better answer here's my analyis. To my taste it's a bit obscure what you are trying to do. Also, I'm not sure whether or not your `\newtheorem` part ist correct.

My hint: If you do new things, don't try to do too much at a time. Better fail early in a controlled way by taking mini-steps.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{thmtools} % <<< this package creates tons of errors at Proof-original

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{plain}

    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

    \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
    \label{lemma:1.11}
    Lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}[Proof of 
% the next command created problems, so I simplified it a little for analysis
\texorpdfstring{\ref{lemma:1.11}}{Lemma 1.1}% check: replacing with an aordinary reference
]
    Proof.
\end{proof}

% lemma:1.1 should be lemma:1.11, see above
\begin{proof}[Proof of \texorpdfstring{\hyperref[lemma:1.11]{Lemma 1.11}}{Lemma 1.11}]
    Proof-original.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]